# Showing commutativity of the ground monoid in a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories, diagram-chasing

I have been trying to understand why the ground monoid in a monoidal category is commutative and every proof I have seen essentially uses the same thing to prove it namely by using the fact(apparently) that if every other subdiagram of a diagram is commutative then the remaining subdiagram is commutative. They all leave the proof of this fact and I don't understand why this should hold. I know that it has something to do with the fact that all the arrows in this diagram are isomorphisms but I don't know the whole picture.

I have added this picture from Vladimir's book on monoidal categories the emphasis here is on the 2nd last paragraph where it states "consequently the lower right triangle commutes"  I don't understand this point.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/59UxI.jpg)[image]

Comment: Yes, you need the fact that all the arrows are isomorphisms. The point is that, if $f$ and $h$ are isomorphisms, then $f \circ g_1 \circ h = f \circ g_2 \circ h$ if and only if $g_1 = g_2$, so you can pre-compose and post-compose as many isomorphisms as you want to prove the identity you need.

Comment: That said, in my view, the coherence isomorphisms are actually not the most important part of the proof. The claim is true in any monoidal category – so in particular it is true in any strict monoidal category, where all the coherence isomorphisms are identity morphisms; yet even in this case there is still something to be proved, so the heart of the proof isn't equation (1.4) on that page. (Spoiler: it is the Eckmann–Hilton argument.)

Comment: @Zhen Lin I understand that part(i.e I get how left tensoring with I implies the equations without I left tensored) but I still don't understand why the lower right triangle must commute.

Comment: It's the same reasoning, except $f$ and $h$ are more complicated and there are more intermediate steps. Start by taking $g_1 = \textrm{id}_I \otimes (l_X \otimes \textrm{id}_Y)$ and $g_2 = (\textrm{id}_I \otimes l_{X \otimes Y}) \circ (\textrm{id}_I \otimes a_{I, X, Y})$.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Thanks Now I understand what you were talking about. I will give this a try now

Comment: @Zhin Lin Do you know of any trivial way to see why the lower right triangle must  commute its just that the wording of the book makes it seem like it can be easily proved and that I am just missing something obvious

Comment: It’s not easy to express precisely (because one first has to make precise definitions) but the point is that if you paste commutative diagrams along matching edges you get another commutative diagram, and if all the arrows involved are isomorphisms you can reverse this process and “subtract” diagrams.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Do you know of any book which goes over this in more detail? I don't have any background in category theory so I am not familiar with the different ways that are involved in proving the commutativity of diagrams

Comment: I am not aware of any books that discuss this. Commutative diagrams are just a way of expressing systems of equations – although there are books discussing how one can prove or disprove equations and there are algorithms for doing so in some contexts, I don't think that's what you need to understand here. (For one thing, _I_ don't know much about equation rewriting either.)

Comment: @Zhin Lin after thinking about It more I got what you meant by adding diagrams can you expand more on the "subtracting diagrams" part

Comment: @Zhin Lin what I got was this: the right parallelogram commutes and the right trapezium commutes so now I just have to prove from this that the lower right triangle comnutes

Comment: @Zhin Lin how would I use the iso property of the arrows to prove this?

Comment: @Zhin Lin I figured it out I just had to equate the two commutative parts and cancel the associativity morphism

Answer (score 3):

$\text{End}(1)$ has two monoid operations. One is composition and the other is tensor product, by which I mean: if $f, g : 1 \to 1$ are two morphisms they have a tensor product $f \otimes g : 1 \otimes 1 \to 1 \otimes 1$, and then we use the unit maps $1 \otimes 1 \cong 1$ to turn this into another endomorphism of $1$. These two monoid operations satisfy the [interchange law](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exchange+law) and so you can run the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument) on them: see for example [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/centers-2-categories-and-the-eckmann-hilton-argument/).

Comment: I proved it the way you described but I had to use this identity $l_{I} =r_{I}$ which is also something I need to prove.

Comment: I was wondering that since the book said "consequently this implies" that there might be something obvious that I am missing which would make it clear why the lower right triangle must commute.